# url mappings with or without trailing slash

Tags: asp.net, url-mapping

I use UrlMappings in web.config. Now, I must have 2 url entries to make the mapping work with both the trailing backslash and without. Like this:

```
<urlMappings>
  <clear />
  <add url="~/app" mappedUrl="~/Templates/Sections/Common/Article.aspx?id=981" />
  <add url="~/app/" mappedUrl="~/Templates/Sections/Common/Article.aspx?id=981" />
</urlMappings>
```

Is it possible to make the url (~/app) work with or without trailing slash, in one line of code? Mabye by using wildcard or something for the "~/app" url..?

Answer (score 0):

The `urlMappings` element doesn't allow for wildcards or regular expressions. A better solution for this problem would be the fully featured [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) (which is an optional module you can install in IIS) which do indeed allow you to write regex's to map your incoming URLs to an internal path.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this by using URL Rewrite instead :)